# Rails: How to check connection with Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I wrote application in Rails. It use Postgresql via VPN. Sometimes VPN is going down and database is not available. How I can check connection with database to avoid error on web page ?

Error :

```
PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "192.168.251.6" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Extracted source (around line #651):

        # connected server's characteristics.
        def connect
          @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)

          # Money type has a fixed precision of 10 in PostgreSQL 8.2 and below, and as of
          # PostgreSQL 8.3 it has a fixed precision of 19. PostgreSQLColumn.extract_precision
```

Any ideas ? And where to check because error is before any controller I think.

Comment: Will this help: `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the PGSQL Driver website,
[PG::Connection](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html), you would want `connect_poll`

```
@connection = PG::Connection.open(@connection_parameters)    
if !@connection.connect_poll
   # do whatever to avoid error on webpage
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Enter following commands on VPN to check pg:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

The PostgreSQL console is indicated by the postgres=# prompt.

```
postgres=# \password pguser
```

where password is the postgres password and 
pguser is the user name of postgres

Enter your desired password at the prompt, and confirm it.

Now you may exit the PostgreSQL console by entering this command:

```
postgres=# \q
```

Comment: Man I need to do it in Ruby on Rails program. I know how to check on linux side :)